# Getting Access Denied Exception when deleting a file in Amazon S3 using the .Net AWSSDK

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to do some simple file IO using amazon S3 and C#.

So far I have been able to create files and list them. I am the bucket owner and I should have full access. In CloudBerry I can create and delete files in the bucket. In my code when I try to delete a file I get an access denied exception.

This is my test method:

```
[Test]
public void TestThatFilesCanBeCreatedAndDeleted()
{
    const string testFile = "test.txt";

    var awsS3Helper = new AwsS3Helper();

    awsS3Helper.AddFileToBucketRoot(testFile);
    var testList = awsS3Helper.ListItemsInBucketRoot();
    Assert.True(testList.ContainsKey(testFile)); // This test passes
    awsS3Helper.DeleteFileFromBucket(testFile); // Access denied exception here
    testList = awsS3Helper.ListItemsInBucketRoot();
    Assert.False(testList.ContainsKey(testFile)); 

}
```

My method to add a file:

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest();
        request.WithBucketName(bucketName);
        request.WithKey(fileName);
        request.WithContentBody("");
        S3Response response = client.PutObject(request);
        response.Dispose();
```

My method to delete a file:

```
var request = new DeleteObjectRequest()
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = fileKey
        };
        S3Response response = client.DeleteObject(request);
        response.Dispose();
```

After running the code the file is visible in CloudBerry and I can delete it from there.

I have very little experience with Amazon S3 so I don't know what could be going wrong. Should I be putting some kind of permissions on to any files I create or upload? Why would I be able to delete a file while I am logged in to CloudBerry with the same credentials provided to my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the source of problem. Possibly security rules, but maybe something very simple with your bucket configuration. You can check them using [S3 Organizer Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/amazon-s3-organizers3fox/), using AWS management site or any other management tool. Also I recommend request-responce logging - that helped a lot in different investigating for me. AWSSDK has plenty of good exmamples with logging - so you need only copy-paste them and everything works. If you have actual requests sending to Amazon, you can compare them with [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/archives/Amazon-S3/123). Please check AccessKeyId for your [deleteRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/SOAPDeleteObject.html)

Comment: Thanks for your great response. It turned out I made a rookie mistake and was causing a lock by creating the client in my constructor and using it throughout my helper class. I used a "using(clientCreatedInConstructor){}" block in each method but the problem was solved by creating the client each time instead i.e. using(Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client()){}. Would have taken me longer to figure that out without your help. Thanks.